# How to recieve data from a one socket and send it to another socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm kind of new to Python and programming. So please forgive me if what I'm about to ask is stupid. So I have this application which connects to the server via port 5555 of the server. So I reconfigured the application to connect to 5555 port of my localhost instead of the actual server. Then I wrote a python program to listen to 127.0.0.1:5555 and send all the data to the actual server. Here's the program

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(("localhost", 5555))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s2:
            s2.connect(("actualserver",5555))
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    print('Sent to the Server :', data)
                    s2.sendall(data)
                data1 = s2.recv(4096)
                if data1:
                    print('Received from the Server :', data1)
                    conn.sendall(data1)
```

So the problem is application tries to connect to the server and gives me the error message "Server didn't respond!".
And this program gives the output like this

```
Sent to the Server : /x87 /x65 blah blah blah
Sent to the Server : /x87 /x65 blah blah blah
Sent to the Server : /x87 /x65 blah blah blah
And an error, saying connection disconnected by an application of your host
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: Can you share the exact error stacktrace? Do you know what the server is doing with the data you send to it?

Comment: If data is sent in one direction but nothing in the other your program will wait for the latter and won't process the former until timeout.

Comment: @OferSadan Of course, Here ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Personal\Projects\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    data = conn.recv(4096)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine```

Comment: @MichaelButscher  I'm sending the data in both directions. I send the data which comes from the application to the server using ```s2.sendall(data)``` and I send the data which comes from the server to application using ```conn.sendall(data1)```

Comment: If e. g. only the application sends data while the server doesn't, your program may wait for some data from server while data from the application isn't processed until timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Change `localhost` and `actualserver` on 127.0.0.1 or another ip, what have opened 5555 port.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.